# Not able to create new project in Xcode

Tags: xcode

Here are the steps I used

1. open Xcode
2. create a new project
3. choose the command line prompt
4. On the the option for new project I put the product name
5. For language I choose C++

Then I can't proceed. At the bottom I see "cancel", "previous",  and "next" but next is greyed out. What do I have to do to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

You must type an Organization Identifier; you can even invent it!